# How to access and save the link present in the body of outlook mail using python

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to access a link from an outlook mail based on the subject "Progress Dashboard". There are multiple links in the body of the mail but I need the one with the name "Instance_List" and save them as a data frame.

**example link:**
(https://s3.data.com/abc-data-inventory/ABCCloud/2019_09_11/ABCCloud_Asia_Instance_List_2019_09_11.csv)

**My final output should be a data frame from the above link**

Tried various codes, sometimes ended up with an error "No module named 'imapclient'" or just able to read the subject of the mail.

Attached the below sample code reference.

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
from imapclient import IMAPClient
import mailparser

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Inbox")
messages = inbox.Items
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Sample Report'")
outputDir = r"C:\CSV_File"

    for message in messages:
        if message.subject == 'Progress Dashboard'
try:
    for message in list(messages):
    try:
        s = message.sender
        for links in message.body:
            links.SaveASFile(os.path.join(outputDir, attachment.FileName))
            print(f"links {file_name} from {s} saved")
    except Exception as e:
        print("error when reading the link:" + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("error when processing emails messages:" + str(e))
```

Comment: First you should install the module [IMAPClient](https://pypi.org/project/IMAPClient/): `pip install IMAPClient`

Comment: Use regex to search the body

Comment: Your link is not working.